# Always Encryption using Azure Function - Trying to Avoid Duplicate Initialization via Static Variables

Tags: c#, thread-safety, azure-functions, azure-keyvault, always-encrypted

I'm using an Azure Function to store encrypted data. I have successfully done so using the code below; however, trying to initialize key store providers more than once throws an error, `Key store providers cannot be set more than once`. To avoid this, I set a static variable to keep track of whether or not it has been initialized or not. This works great for short periods of time. However, every time I try for the first time the next day, the Function bombs out with the same error. What is interesting to me is that if the `isInitialized` static variable is losing its value after some period of time, shouldn't the `_clientCredential` variable also be reset, meaning that trying to set the providers again is okay?

```
private static ClientCredential _clientCredential;
private static Boolean isInitialized;

if (isInitialized == false) {
    isInitialized = true;
    string clientId = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["blah"].ConnectionString;
    string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["blah"].ConnectionString;
    _clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

    SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider azureKeyVaultProvider = new SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider(GetToken);

    Dictionary<string, SqlColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProvider> providers = new Dictionary<string, SqlColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProvider>();
    providers.Add(SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider.ProviderName, azureKeyVaultProvider);

    SqlConnection.RegisterColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProviders(providers);
}
```

It seems one of the variables is being reset and not the other. I understand that there are also thread safety issues using Azure Functions. Is there some other way to check if it's still initialized altogether to avoid thread safety issues completely? Or do I somehow need to avoid thread safety issues and the session state myself?

I have seen one other post on this topic, but with no real explanation on how to handle the issues explained above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static members are shared across different invocations of the same function which can lead to race conditions. Use Static constructors to initialize shared resources.